# Rails turn URL string into hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm iterating over a table to kick out link title and link urls for each additional item thats being added by a user. Ultimately I want a very basic: 
Title, URL

I need the URL to be clickable and I'm hitting a wall.

```
  <tbody>
    <% @links.each do |link| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= link_to link.url %></td>
    <td><%= link.title %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', link %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', link, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Right now the link_to link.url will display the correct link but the link redirects back to the homepage. I've also tried:

- url_to link.url 
  error message that says "did you mean url_for"
- url_for link.url 
  which removes a hyperlink
- link_to("#{link.url}")
  which has the same issue my code above in that it links back home
- link_to("#{@link.url}") 
  which returns an error of: undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
- link_url("#{link.url}") 
  returns the entire localhost address and then the link...not a hyperlink
- auto_link(link.url)
  returns an error asking if I meant autoload

Surely I'm missing something that's super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your reference [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

the format is

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
```

for your problem

```
<td><%= link_to link.url, "http://#{link.url}" %></td>
```

Comment: Close but it's still keeping the original route to local host. Example: http://localhost:3000/www.google.com